# IOS/Objective-c: Access a ViewController with a button, "opposing" the storyBoard structure

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a storyBoard like this:

[image]

The yellow VC is where i can add spots to a mapKit (the app starts with it). The only way to access the yellow VC is through the table view, witch has a button. And when the spot is created, the table view is again displayed (the instruction is on the save button of the yellow VC) with the new data. My question is: can I show the mapKit instead the tableView without changing this structure? I tried something like

```
MapViewController *map = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:map animated:YES];
```

on the save new spot button, but nothing happened...Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a identifier to your ViewController and then the following code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"nameOfStoryBoard" bundle:nil];
MapViewController *mapController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourViewControllerIdentifier"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mapController animated:YES];
```

StoryboardID is the identifier for your viewcontroller in the right panel

[image: StoryboardID is the identifier for your viewcontroller in the right panel]

Comment: i'm missing something, sorry. I have a crash with the log saying he doesnt know the storyboard. Where can I identify it. Isnt't the name of the file? Main.storyboard

Comment: the name of the Storyboard is the name of your file probably "Main"

Comment: now it doesnt crash, but nothing happens... I Have it like this:  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        MapViewController *mapController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"map"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapController animated:YES];

Comment: you should have a navigationController to push into, in storyboard create a NavigationController to be the entry point and after that connect your TabbarController.

Comment: but I already have one navController. Are you saying to create another?

Comment: if you already have an instance of navController the code should work, but if your navController return nil your viewcontroller will not displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136403/discussion-between-calc91-and-fumanchu).